# SQL select some rows in a table so that they sum up to certain value

Tags: mysql, select, sum

How can I select just some rows in the following table so that they sum up to certain value?

```
Table
-----
id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
------------------------------
1  | 0.0  | 0.0  | 10   | 20
2  | 1.5  | 0.0  | 7.5  | 18
3  | 1.0  | 2.0  | 7.5  | 18
4  | 0.0  | 0.5  | 5    | 13
```

Let's say, the top value I want is 57...

So I need to select the rows from the previous table such that qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4 of each row, get until that 57 value, and discard the other rows. In this example, I would get the following:

```
id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
------------------------------
1  | 0.0  | 0.0  | 10   | 20
2  | 1.5  | 0.0  | 7.5  | 18
```

Because 10+20+1.5+7.5+18 = 57, so I discard rows 3 & 4...

Now I wish that the top value is 50, then I should get:

```
id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
------------------------------
1  | 0.0  | 0.0  | 10   | 20
2  | 1.5  | 0.0  | 7.5  | 11
```

Since these values sum up to 50, and the 7 from row2,qty4 is left out...
(BTW the rows are ordered in this particular way because that's the order in which I wish to account for the sums of qtys... It's not valid to sum up first row1, then 3, then 2 then 4, for example... They should always be sumed in the order 1,2,3,4...)

What if I would like the complement of this? I mean, the other two rows I didn't got in the last result.

First case:

```
id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
------------------------------
3  | 1.0  | 2.0  | 7.5  | 18
4  | 0.0  | 0.5  | 5    | 13
```

Second case:

```
id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
------------------------------
2  | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0  | 7
3  | 1.0  | 2.0  | 7.5  | 18
4  | 0.0  | 0.5  | 5    | 13
```

(If the second case is too complicated, how about obtaining:

```
id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
------------------------------
1  | 0.0  | 0.0  | 10   | 20
```

Because adding up the original qtys of row 2 would surpass the 50 value, I discard it...
The complement in this case should just be:

```
id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
------------------------------
2  | 1.5  | 0.0  | 7.5  | 18
3  | 1.0  | 2.0  | 7.5  | 18
4  | 0.0  | 0.5  | 5    | 13
```

)

Comment: I've written lots of complex queries, and I like taking on a challenge, but this is one of those rare cases that just begs for you to write procedural code in the language of your choice.

Comment: even for the simplified second case? the last ones in parentheses at the end of the post... ?

Comment: The simplified second case is doable as a query. If you modify your question to ask for just that (or create a new question that asks for just that), I can help.

Comment: fo 300 I'll have to explain you every detail of the real problem I'm facing, instead of just showing the particular details abstracted as an example here, so the solutions you give are not just generalizations that I'll have to translate or adapt, but the actual solution I need for my problem. And I'll have you sign an NDA because that details are things on my job and they're supposed not to be known for anyone... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's put it this way: If SQL was a religion I'd go to hell for providing this solution. SQL is not meant to solve this kind of problems, so any solution would be horrible. Mine is no exception :)

```
set @limitValue := 50;
select id, newQty1, newQty2, newQty3, newQty4 from (
  select id,
  if(@limitValue - qty1 > 0, qty1, greatest(@limitValue, 0)) newQty1,
  @limitValue := @limitValue - qty1 Total1,
  if(@limitValue - qty2 > 0, qty2, greatest(@limitValue, 0)) newQty2,
  @limitValue := @limitValue - qty2 Total2,
  if(@limitValue - qty3 > 0, qty3, greatest(@limitValue, 0)) newQty3,
  @limitValue := @limitValue - qty3 Total3,
  if(@limitValue - qty4 > 0, qty4, greatest(@limitValue, 0)) newQty4,
  @limitValue := @limitValue - qty4 Total4
  from (
    select id, qty1, qty2, qty3, qty4,
      @rowTotal < @limitValue Useful,
      @previousRowTotal := @rowTotal PreviousRowTotal,
      @rowTotal := @rowTotal + qty1 + qty2 + qty3 + qty4 AllRowsTotal,
      @rowTotal - @previousRowTotal CurrentRowTotal 
    from t,
    (select @rowTotal := 0, @previousRowTotal := 0) S1
  ) MarkedUseful
  where useful = 1
) Final
```

For the provided data, this results in:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID | NEWQTY1 | NEWQTY2 | NEWQTY3 | NEWQTY4 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 0       |       0 | 10      |      20 |
|  2 | 1.5     |       0 | 7.5     |      11 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

And the complement:

```
set @limitValue := 50;
select t1.id,
  coalesce(t1.qty1 - newQty1, t1.qty1) newQty1,
  coalesce(t1.qty2 - newQty2, t1.qty2) newQty2,
  coalesce(t1.qty3 - newQty3, t1.qty3) newQty3,
  coalesce(t1.qty4 - newQty4, t1.qty4) newQty4
from t t1 left join (
    select id,
    if(@limitValue - qty1 > 0, qty1, greatest(@limitValue, 0)) newQty1,
    @limitValue := @limitValue - qty1 Total1,
    if(@limitValue - qty2 > 0, qty2, greatest(@limitValue, 0)) newQty2,
    @limitValue := @limitValue - qty2 Total2,
    if(@limitValue - qty3 > 0, qty3, greatest(@limitValue, 0)) newQty3,
    @limitValue := @limitValue - qty3 Total3,
    if(@limitValue - qty4 > 0, qty4, greatest(@limitValue, 0)) newQty4,
    @limitValue := @limitValue - qty4 Total4
    from (
      select id, qty1, qty2, qty3, qty4,
        @rowTotal < @limitValue Useful,
        @previousRowTotal := @rowTotal PreviousRowTotal,
        @rowTotal := @rowTotal + qty1 + qty2 + qty3 + qty4 AllRowsTotal,
        @rowTotal - @previousRowTotal CurrentRowTotal 
      from t,
      (select @rowTotal := 0, @previousRowTotal := 0) S1
    ) MarkedUseful
    where useful = 1
) Final
on t1.id = final.id
where Total1 < 0 or Total2 < 0 or Total3 < 0 or Total4 < 0 or final.id is null
```

For the provided data, this results in:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID | NEWQTY1 | NEWQTY2 | NEWQTY3 | NEWQTY4 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  2 |       0 | 0       | 0       |       7 |
|  3 |       1 | 2       | 7.5     |      18 |
|  4 |       0 | 0.5     | 5       |      13 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Enjoy!

Comment: just tried the provided solutions, but for the complement case, using the same sample data, I didn't got the result you show, but just the original 4 rows from the data table...

Comment: now it works! I don't know what have I done wrong last time :) Let me test it and apply it to my real case and I'll give you an answer about the bounty ;)

Answer (score 13):

The simplified option in parentheses is not too bad:

```
SELECT foo1.*
  FROM foo AS foo1
  JOIN foo AS foo2
    ON foo2.id <= foo1.id
 GROUP
    BY foo1.id
HAVING SUM(foo2.qty1 + foo2.qty2 + foo2.qty3 + foo2.qty4) <= 57
;
```

(You didn't mention the table's name, so I went with `foo`.)

The complement would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM foo
 WHERE id NOT IN
        ( SELECT foo1.id
            FROM foo AS foo1
            JOIN foo AS foo2
              ON foo2.id <= foo1.id
           GROUP
              BY foo1.id
          HAVING SUM(foo2.qty1 + foo2.qty2 + foo2.qty3 + foo2.qty4) <= 57
        )
;
```

The unparenthesized option is much trickier; it's doable, but you'd be much better off using a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines.html).

Answer (score 4):

Let's load your sample data from the question

```
mysql> drop database if exists javier;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> create database javier;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> use javier
Database changed
mysql> create table mytable
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     qty1 float,qty2 float,qty3 float,qty4 float,
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable (qty1,qty2,qty3,qty4) values
    -> ( 0.0 , 0.0 , 10  , 20 ),( 1.5 , 0.0 , 7.5 , 18 ),
    -> ( 1.0 , 2.0 , 7.5 , 18 ),( 0.0 , 0.5 , 5   , 13 );
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    0 |    0 |   10 |   20 |
|  2 |  1.5 |    0 |  7.5 |   18 |
|  3 |    1 |    2 |  7.5 |   18 |
|  4 |    0 |  0.5 |    5 |   13 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## **FINAL QUERY THAT FULLY WORKS**

```
select BBBB.* from (select id,sums FROM (select A.id,A.sums from
(select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB 
where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 50 mylimit) B ON A.sums <= B.mylimit) AAA
UNION
(select A.id,A.sums from (select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4)  
from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
where A.sums=(select min(A.sums) sums from (select id, 
(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums 
from mytable AA order by id) A INNER JOIN (SELECT 50 mylimit) B 
ON A.sums >= B.mylimit))) AAAA JOIN mytable BBBB USING (id);
```

## **FINAL QUERY COMPLEMENT THAT FULLY WORKS**

```
select BBBB.* from  mytable BBBB LEFT JOIN
(select id,sums FROM (select A.id,A.sums from ( 
select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4)  
from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums 
from mytable AA order by id) A INNER JOIN
(SELECT 50 mylimit) B ON A.sums <= B.mylimit) AAA
UNION
(select A.id,A.sums from (select id, 
(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB 
where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
where A.sums=(select min(A.sums) sums from ( 
select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB 
where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 50 mylimit) B ON A.sums >= B.mylimit))) AAAA
USING (id) WHERE AAAA.id IS NULL;
```

Here is the output for 57

```
mysql>     select BBBB.* from (select id,sums FROM (select A.id,A.sums from
    ->     (select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB
    ->     where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
    ->     INNER JOIN (SELECT 57 mylimit) B ON A.sums <= B.mylimit) AAA
    ->     UNION
    ->     (select A.id,A.sums from (select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4)
    ->     from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
    ->     where A.sums=(select min(A.sums) sums from (select id,
    ->     (select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums
    ->     from mytable AA order by id) A INNER JOIN (SELECT 57 mylimit) B
    ->     ON A.sums >= B.mylimit))) AAAA JOIN mytable BBBB USING (id);
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    0 |    0 |   10 |   20 |
|  2 |  1.5 |    0 |  7.5 |   18 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>     select BBBB.* from  mytable BBBB LEFT JOIN
    ->     (select id,sums FROM (select A.id,A.sums from (
    ->     select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4)
    ->     from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums
    ->     from mytable AA order by id) A INNER JOIN
    ->     (SELECT 57 mylimit) B ON A.sums <= B.mylimit) AAA
    ->     UNION
    ->     (select A.id,A.sums from (select id,
    ->     (select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB
    ->     where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
    ->     where A.sums=(select min(A.sums) sums from (
    ->     select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB
    ->     where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
    ->     INNER JOIN (SELECT 57 mylimit) B ON A.sums >= B.mylimit))) AAAA
    ->     USING (id) WHERE AAAA.id IS NULL;
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  3 |    1 |    2 |  7.5 |   18 |
|  4 |    0 |  0.5 |    5 |   13 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the output for 50

```
mysql>     select BBBB.* from (select id,sums FROM (select A.id,A.sums from
    ->     (select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB
    ->     where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
    ->     INNER JOIN (SELECT 50 mylimit) B ON A.sums <= B.mylimit) AAA
    ->     UNION
    ->     (select A.id,A.sums from (select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4)
    ->     from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
    ->     where A.sums=(select min(A.sums) sums from (select id,
    ->     (select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums
    ->     from mytable AA order by id) A INNER JOIN (SELECT 50 mylimit) B
    ->     ON A.sums >= B.mylimit))) AAAA JOIN mytable BBBB USING (id);
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    0 |    0 |   10 |   20 |
|  2 |  1.5 |    0 |  7.5 |   18 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>     select BBBB.* from  mytable BBBB LEFT JOIN
    ->     (select id,sums FROM (select A.id,A.sums from (
    ->     select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4)
    ->     from mytable BB where BB.id<=AA.id) sums
    ->     from mytable AA order by id) A INNER JOIN
    ->     (SELECT 50 mylimit) B ON A.sums <= B.mylimit) AAA
    ->     UNION
    ->     (select A.id,A.sums from (select id,
    ->     (select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB
    ->     where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
    ->     where A.sums=(select min(A.sums) sums from (
    ->     select id,(select sum(qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4) from mytable BB
    ->     where BB.id<=AA.id) sums from mytable AA order by id) A
    ->     INNER JOIN (SELECT 50 mylimit) B ON A.sums >= B.mylimit))) AAAA
    ->     USING (id) WHERE AAAA.id IS NULL;
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  3 |    1 |    2 |  7.5 |   18 |
|  4 |    0 |  0.5 |    5 |   13 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Please remember to set the number for mylimit in the `(SELECT 50 mylimit)` subquery twice each.

Please tell I got this one...

Comment: thanks :) however this just solves the simple case I proposed, not the complex one ;)

Comment: @Javier What is the complex one ? If you mean using some other number like 50, just replace `(SELECT 57 mylimit)` with `(SELECT 50 mylimit)` in both queries (the FINAL and FINAL COMPLEMENT) and they will work perfectly. Otherwise, please explain the complex case.

Comment: I'll try to explain by example, using sample data I gave. With mylimit=50, result of the query should give for id=2: qty1=1.5, qty2=0.0, qty3=7.5, qty4=11. However, your queries gives me no row for id=2. As you can see, qty4=11 is not what the table has in its data, but is the result of adding the values of qty1+qty2+qty3+qty4 on each row until the mylimit value is reached. That is, 50 is reached when you add: row1.qty1+row1.qty2+row1.qty3+row1.qty4 then +row2.qty1+row2.qty2+row2.qty3 then +7 which is substracted from the original row2.qty4=18, which gives the 7 you see on the desired result

Comment: Hi Javier, just checking in. Please check the FINAL QUERY and FINAL QUERY COMPLEMENT. They fully work for 57 and 50.

Comment: I cleaned up my answer so that the working queries are on top. I included full examples of 57 and 50 being executed.

Answer (score 4):

You should adjust only the @limit variable initialization in the `init` subquery. The first query outputs data up to limit, the secnd query outputs its complement.

```
SELECT
  id,
  @qty1 as qty1,
  @qty2 as qty2,
  @qty3 as qty3,
  @qty4 as qty4
FROM quantities q,
  (SELECT @qty1:=0.0, @qty2:=0.0,
          @qty3:=0.0, @qty4:=0.0,
          @limit:=50.0) init
WHERE
  IF(@limit > 0,
     GREATEST(1,
       IF(@limit-qty1 >=0,
          @limit:=(@limit-(@qty1:=qty1)),
          @qty1:=@limit + LEAST(@limit, @limit:=0)),
       IF(@limit-qty2 >=0,
          @limit:=(@limit-(@qty2:=qty2)),
          @qty2:=@limit + LEAST(@limit, @limit:=0)),
       IF(@limit-qty3 >=0,
          @limit:=(@limit-(@qty3:=qty3)),
          @qty3:=@limit + LEAST(@limit, @limit:=0)),
       IF(@limit-qty4 >=0,
          @limit:=(@limit-(@qty4:=qty4)),
          @qty4:=@limit + LEAST(@limit, @limit:=0))),0)
;
```

The complement:

```
SELECT
  id,
  IF(qty1=@qty1, qty1, qty1-@qty1) as qty1,
  IF(qty2=@qty2, qty2, qty2-@qty2) as qty2,
  IF(qty3=@qty3, qty3, qty3-@qty3) as qty3,
  IF(qty4=@qty4, qty4, qty4-@qty4) as qty4
FROM quantities q,
  (SELECT @qty1:=0.0, @qty2:=0.0,
          @qty3:=0.0, @qty4:=0.0,
          @limit:=50.0) init
WHERE
  IF(
    LEAST(
      IF(@limit-qty1 >=0,
         @limit:=(@limit-(@qty1:=qty1)),
         @qty1:=@limit + LEAST(@limit, @limit:=0)),
      IF(@limit-qty2 >=0,
         @limit:=(@limit-(@qty2:=qty2)),
         @qty2:=@limit + LEAST(@limit, @limit:=0)),
      IF(@limit-qty3 >=0,
         @limit:=(@limit-(@qty3:=qty3)),
         @qty3:=@limit + LEAST(@limit, @limit:=0)),
      IF(@limit-qty4 >=0,
         @limit:=(@limit-(@qty4:=qty4)),
         @qty4:=@limit + LEAST(@limit, @limit:=0)),
      @limit), 0, 1)
;
```

Comment: thanks! it do works with the sample data. let me test it with my real data and I'll answer you about the bounty...